# Retain inter-word spacing in math mode

Tags: math-mode, pandoc, white-space

Is there a shorthand/ instruction for `math mode` to simply retain words and not collapse the whitespace?  I.e. rather than manually inserting spacing after each word with `\,` and friends.

Here is the text I would like to have be treated like text with math symbols:

```
$${(i,t) where i \in {Truths} and t \in {Actuals Sets} and {Truths_i} \cap {Actuals_t} \ne \o}$$
```

The result is that the non-symbol words are collapsed into a  mush:

[image]

While it is possible to fix this manually (using `\,` and friends):

```
$${(i,t)\, where\, i \in {Truths}\, and\, t \in {Actuals Sets}\, and\, {Truths_i} \cap {Actuals_t} \ne \o}
```

.. resulting in :

[image]
That seems like *too much manual work*.

What are the options here?

Comment: Are you interested in something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYfmm.png)?

Comment: @Werner yes. care to spill the beans?

Comment: You're going to have to do some legwork, since you're setting textual content in math mode. Is this supposed to be in a `$$`...`$$` display? And you're using Pandoc? Try with `(i,t) \mbox{ where } i \in \mathrm{Truths} \mbox{ and } 
    t \in \mathrm{Actuals~Sets} \mbox{ and }
    \mathrm{Truths}_i \cap \mathrm{Actuals}_t \neq \mbox{\o}`.

Comment: wow that's even *more* work than `\,` and ilk.  No way to _en masse_ get a "phrase" to be parsed like a sentence ?  Well i'm guessing not then ..  Is there no package that can help?

Comment: There's no *magical* way to detect that `t` in `(i,t)` should be math while `t` in `Actuals` should not text. And the same goes for all the other non-symbols you're using. So, no, there is no *en masse* magical way to do it. If you're interested in a quality end result, then you're going to have to spill some beans here and there... ;) Maybe someone else has a better suggestions with fewer keystrokes since that seems to be a concern for you here...

Comment: the missing spaces are the _least_ of the problems with the output you show. you have set the letters in the math italic font which is designed to make adjacent letters _not_ look like a word but as a product of variables. If you use `\text`   then a font and word space suitable fro words will be used.

Answer (score 3):

The following screenshot provides solutions for both inline math mode and display math mode. The solutions rely on the `\text` and `\textup` macros. `\textup` (or `\textnormal`) should be used for variable names; that way, they'll get typeset in the upright regardless of whether the surrounding happens to be typeset in italics (say, because the material occurs in the body of a theorem).

I also suggest replacing `\o` with `\emptyset`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\text" macro
\begin{document}
\noindent
$(i,t)$, where $i\in\textup{Truths}$ and $t\in\textup{Actuals Sets}$
and $\textup{Truths}_i\cap\textup{Actuals}_t \ne \emptyset$
\[
\text{$(i,t)$, where $i\in\textup{Truths}$ and $t\in\textup{Actuals Sets}$
and $\textup{Truths}_i\cap\textup{Actuals}_t \ne \emptyset$}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: looks like we had similar thoughts on this.

Comment: While “where” can be in `\text`, the other parts are names of variables and should probably be `\textup` or `\textnormal`.

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for this suggestion; I've modified the LaTeX code accordingly.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You seem to have missed my answer that _preceded_ this one and includes `\text{}` .  Oh - you _did see it .. but did not credit it in your comment.  More fair to say would be there are similarities and differences.

Answer (score 2):

You should define a suitable environment for such “textual equations”:

Here I define `textequation*` (based on `equation*`); a `textequation` version for numbering is similar. I also increase the baselineskip, which is common in displayed material.

The optional argument (default 0.8) is a factor for setting a width, see the example below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\newcommand{\tvar}[1]{% textual variable
  \textnormal{#1}%
}
\newenvironment{textequation*}[1][0.8]
 {\begin{equation*}\begin{minipage}{#1\displaywidth}\linespread{1.2}\selectfont}
 {\end{minipage}\end{equation*}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[4]
\begin{textequation*}
  $(i,t)$ where $i \in \tvar{Truths}$ and $t \in \tvar{Actuals Sets}$ and
  $\tvar{Truths}_i \cap \tvar{Actuals}_t \ne \emptyset$
\end{textequation*}
\lipsum*[4]
\begin{textequation*}[0.6]
  $(i,t)$ where $i \in \tvar{Truths}$ and $t \in \tvar{Actuals Sets}$ and
  $\tvar{Truths}_i \cap \tvar{Actuals}_t \ne \emptyset$
\end{textequation*}
\lipsum*[4]

\end{document}
```

Using a special command for the “textual variables” is recommended, so you don't have surprises when typesetting them.

[image]

Comment: How much of this structure is applicable to a `markdown` doc with various _snippets_ of `tex`  and that is processed by `pandoc` ?   It seems the document header portion is instead handled by the `pandoc` `yaml` header .. ?

Comment: @javadba I really don't know. Markdown seems to me quite inadequate for complex tasks.

Answer (score 0):

After some more looking the best I could find so far is to use `\text{some prose here}` (oh and also breaking it into two lines and aligning) :

```
$$\begin{aligned}
      \{(i,t)\text{ where i}\in \{TruthGrpIds\}\text{ and }t \in \{Actuals SetIds\} \\
      \text{ and }\{Truths_i\} \cap \{Actuals_t\} \ne \varnothing \} \\
\end{aligned}$$
```

[image]

While I will keep an eye out for some further improvements, this will likely be the approach for the near term.

Comment: A couple of things: The insertion of `\text` is similar to `\mbox` in my comments above. Also, `TruthGrpIds` have some "not nice" spacing between the characters, since they're considered symbols (letters) multiplied by one another in math mode. Note the horrible kerning between `I` and `d` when compared to (say) `\mathit{TruthGrpIds}`. Also, note the space missing in `Actuals SetIds`... you need a `~`. Finally, why `aligned` and not `gathered`?

Comment: `aligned` not `gathered` : since I have a one-word vocabulary so far. trying the latter on for size now

Comment: got this: `Erroneous nesting of equation structures;  (amsmath)  trying to recover with _aligned_`  btw feel free to add an answer: you have useful ideas and at least can upvote it

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwwxv.png) is the output when using `gathered` - it centres things rather than having them right-aligned as in your setup.

Comment: any idea why `gathered` failed with that error message?

Comment: No idea. This is [the code](https://pastebin.com/Y539mWAE) I used. Not sure whether you can use `\[`...`\]` in markdown or whether it requires `$$`...`$$`.

Comment: You still are using the math italic font for "Truiths" etc which makes it hard to read as a word (as the font uses wide sidebearings so that adjacent letters do not look like a word) use `\mathrm{Truths}` or, if you want italic, `\mathit{Truths}`

Comment: also you should not use `$$` in latex, and not use `aligned` if you have no alignment points (`&`)

Comment: $$ is since this is `markdown` .  the alignment is actually working decently